# how to add 10 days to the current date?

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker

I have code that implements a calendar:

```
$( function() {
    var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
    from = $( "#fromdate" ).datepicker({
        minDate:0,
        changeMonth: true
    }).on( "change", function() {
        to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
    }),
    to = $( "#todate" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true
    }).on( "change", function() {
        from.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
    });

    function getDate( element ) {
        var date;
        try {
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
        } catch( error ) {
            date = null;
        }
        return date;
    }
});
```

I have the `#fromdate` and `#todate` HTML elements. I want `#fromdate` to select the current date (it does that), and `#todate` to add 10 days to it (this doesn't work), and show it on the calendar.

Comment: This is all javascript, are you trying to do it in javascript or in PHP?

Comment: I believe you meant JavaScript: `var myDate = new Date(new Date().getTime()+(10*24*60*60*1000));`

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
$date = strtotime($date);
$date = strtotime("+10 day", $date);
echo date('M d, Y', $date);
```